# What query I to use to export records in mysql at server side

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to export all records from phpMyAdmin.In my table "unique_req" has total 45215 records When I export it with the tab "Export" in phpMyAdmin, I am not getting the complete records of that table.

I have also tried it with export query at server side but with this its giving me a error of "Access Denied". Its working fine when I am exporting it in local machine but at server side I got error "Access Denied".

What should I to do to export all records of a table..

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty explicit : the mysql user you are using to query the production database does not have enough rights. You need to edit the privileges related to your user on the production mysql server.